# Block device full - how do I clear space

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, disk-usage, devices

I'm a relatively basic user, using the Ubuntu terminal for Windows. I have a failing deployment caused by a lack of disk space on the VM I'm connected to in the terminal:

`df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda1        30G   30G     0 100% /
```

`/dev/` exists as a regular directory. I then see `sda1` as a block device file:

`ls -l`

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8,   1 Aug 12 01:31 sda1
```

(See https://superuser.com/questions/1240857/is-dev-sda1-a-directory/1594704#1594704 for an explanation of a block file).

How do I investigate what's filling up the block, and remove unneccessary data?

If I `cd sda1` I get `Not a directory`

Comment: sda1 will be your disk, /dev is a DEVICE directory and POSIX (or older UNIX) philosophy says everything is treated as a file. The first "b" in the directory shows it's a BLOCK device and you're chasing down the wrong places.. Look for files that are using space, not devices.  (FYI: that device will use none of your disk space; it's more a logical item that represents the whole disk;  if you find your keyboard - it likewise will use no disk space!)

Comment: fyi:  I should have said partition, sda would be the disk, sda1 is the partition on the disk

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/sdaN` is not a directory, but a reference to the Nth partition of your hard drive. `df -h` shows that `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/`. If you want to see what is taking up space on a device, you look in that device's mount point, in this case `/`.

Comment: Thanks @Pixelated Fish. If I try `du -s /*` in the root as described here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125430/204761, I get a lot of `cannot read directory ... Permission denied` messages, and none of the directories that can be read appear to have significant disk usage. Any ideas?

Comment: You can avoid the permission denied error by omitting the *, as it will search directories you, well... don't have permission to :) You can also try running it as root by placing `sudo` at the beginning of the command. You can also edit your answer and post the result there.

Comment: Thanks @Pixelated Fish - this helped me locate the problem - I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I realised `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/` - @Pixelated Fish's answer explains this is the 1st partition of the hard drive. So now I can

`sudo du -s /`, which reveals that something in the `/var` directory is the culprit. Drilling down I find that `/var/lib/docker` is the issue - which made me suspect that old docker images from automated deployments aren't being removed, which is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images.

I also did `sudo -s`, `cd /` and `df -h`, which then showed the exact culprit directory (I'm not sure why this worked, when `df -h` without being the root user didn't). It turned out log files were the issue. I can `cd` to the folder and `rm *` to clear out the files.

The following question has approaches around locating what's taking up disk space:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/tracking-down-where-disk-space-has-gone-on-linux

Comment: When using docker, make a script that prunes unused images on a weekly basis.